# MVC Resource causes 404 Not Found with Spring MVC & Tiles

Tags: java, css, spring-mvc

I have a working MVC application with tiles.  However, I am having trouble with the MVC Resource.  If I do not include the mvc:resources in my xml file or refer to it in the html to the CSS files, I can successfully view the pages.  However, if I add the resource tags in, it gives me a "The requested resource is not available" error - preventing me from seeing the page at all.

Could you assist me in determining the cause for this?  I have tried to follow the documentation and the myriad of tutorials for it - however it doesn't seem to work.  Thanks!

---

**EDIT: I know there are multiple questions addressing this - I have browsed through the vast majority of them (both on and off Stack Overflow) and tried solutions with no success.**

**EDIT: After some troubleshooting, I determined that my controllers are successfully accessed (by seeing the logging data).  It cannot find "/ContactManagement/WEB-INF/jsp/layout.jsp".  This only occurs once I refer to .  I commented out the CSS file references in my views; however, that does not fix it.**

**Mapping is completed for all the controllers now, as well as the mvc:resources mapping.  It's just the .jsp files that it is having trouble accessing.**

---

In my configuration file, I include the MVC resources through

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

I refer to in in the html as

```
<link href="<c:url value='/resources/css/default.css'/>" rel="stylesheet" />
```

My file structure is

```
-WebContent
---resources
------css
------js
------images
---WEB-INF
------jsp
------spring-servlet.xml
------tiles.xml
```

Here is my spring-servlet.xml

```
    <?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}" p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}"
    p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}" />

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass">
        <value>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="tilesConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<context:component-scan base-package="mil.navy.navsupbsc" />
```

Here is the head of the HTML layout page

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="type" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<%-- href="<c:url value="/resources/css/default.css"/>"  --%>
<link   
 href="<c:url value='/resources/css/default.css'/>" rel="stylesheet" />

<title><tiles:insertAttribute name="title" ignore="true" /></title>
</head>
```

Here are my startup logs

```
Jan 31, 2014 9:16:26 PM com.springsource.tcserver.security.PropertyDecoder <init>
INFO: tc Runtime property decoder using memory-based key
Jan 31, 2014 9:16:26 PM com.springsource.tcserver.security.PropertyDecoder <init>
INFO: tcServer Runtime property decoder has been initialized in 392 ms
Jan 31, 2014 9:16:27 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-48080"]
Jan 31, 2014 9:16:27 PM com.springsource.tcserver.serviceability.rmi.JmxSocketListener init
INFO: Started up JMX registry on 127.0.0.1:46969 in 224 ms
Jan 31, 2014 9:16:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1393 ms
Jan 31, 2014 9:16:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jan 31, 2014 9:16:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: VMware vFabric tc Runtime 2.9.3.RELEASE/7.0.42.A.RELEASE
Jan 31, 2014 9:16:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor C:\Program Files\Spring Toolsuite\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.9.3.RELEASE\base-instance\conf\Catalina\localhost\ContactManagement.xml
Jan 31, 2014 9:16:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:ContactManagement' did not find a matching property.
Jan 31, 2014 9:16:27 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Program Files\Spring Toolsuite\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.9.3.RELEASE\base-instance\wtpwebapps\ContactManagement\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api-2.5.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Jan 31, 2014 9:16:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Jan 31, 2014 9:16:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'spring'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'spring': initialization started
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'spring-servlet': startup date [Fri Jan 31 21:16:30 EST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer - Loading properties file from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties]
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource - Loaded JDBC driver: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer - TilesConfigurer: adding definitions [/WEB-INF/tiles.xml]
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.apache.tiles.context.AbstractTilesApplicationContextFactory - Initializing Tiles2 application context. . .
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.apache.tiles.context.AbstractTilesApplicationContextFactory - Finished initializing Tiles2 application context.
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.apache.tiles.access.TilesAccess - Publishing TilesContext for context: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.SpringTilesApplicationContextFactory$SpringWildcardServletTilesApplicationContext
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0'

    2014-01-31 21:01:01,513 INFO [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator] - <HHH000229: Running schema validator>
    [...Database Validation...]

[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager - Using DataSource [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource@1ca09d2] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'spring': initialization completed in 11998 ms
Jan 31, 2014 9:16:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Spring Toolsuite\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.9.3.RELEASE\base-instance\webapps\manager
Jan 31, 2014 9:16:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Spring Toolsuite\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.9.3.RELEASE\base-instance\webapps\ROOT
Jan 31, 2014 9:16:42 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-48080"]
Jan 31, 2014 9:16:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 15126 ms
```

When I hit the page, it comes up with the following:

```
[tomcat-http--3] WARN org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/ContactManagement/contact] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
```

EDIT: I ran it without the mvc resource tags and it came up with these additional lines in the log (makes me think that for some reason it isn't mapping the controllers when i include the resource tags):

```
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/addressType] onto handler 'addressTypeController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/addressType.*] onto handler 'addressTypeController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/addressType/] onto handler 'addressTypeController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/addressType/.*] onto handler 'addressTypeController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/addressType/add] onto handler 'addressTypeController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/addressType/add.*] onto handler 'addressTypeController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/addressType/add/] onto handler 'addressTypeController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/addressType/delete/{addressTypeId}] onto handler 'addressTypeController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/addressType/delete/{addressTypeId}.*] onto handler 'addressTypeController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/addressType/delete/{addressTypeId}/] onto handler 'addressTypeController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/addresstype] onto handler 'addressTypeController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/addresstype.*] onto handler 'addressTypeController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/addresstype/] onto handler 'addressTypeController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/addresstype/.*] onto handler 'addressTypeController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/addresstype/add] onto handler 'addressTypeController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/addresstype/add.*] onto handler 'addressTypeController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/addresstype/add/] onto handler 'addressTypeController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/addresstype/delete/{addressTypeId}] onto handler 'addressTypeController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/addresstype/delete/{addressTypeId}.*] onto handler 'addressTypeController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/addresstype/delete/{addressTypeId}/] onto handler 'addressTypeController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/contact] onto handler 'contactController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/contact.*] onto handler 'contactController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/contact/] onto handler 'contactController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/contact/.*] onto handler 'contactController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/country] onto handler 'countryController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/country.*] onto handler 'countryController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/country/] onto handler 'countryController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/country/.*] onto handler 'countryController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/country/add] onto handler 'countryController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/country/add.*] onto handler 'countryController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/country/add/] onto handler 'countryController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/country/delete/{countryId}] onto handler 'countryController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/country/delete/{countryId}.*] onto handler 'countryController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/country/delete/{countryId}/] onto handler 'countryController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/emailtype] onto handler 'emailTypeController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/emailtype.*] onto handler 'emailTypeController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/emailtype/] onto handler 'emailTypeController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/emailtype/.*] onto handler 'emailTypeController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/emailtype/delete/{emailTypeId}] onto handler 'emailTypeController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/emailtype/delete/{emailTypeId}.*] onto handler 'emailTypeController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/emailtype/delete/{emailTypeId}/] onto handler 'emailTypeController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/emailtype/add] onto handler 'emailTypeController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/emailtype/add.*] onto handler 'emailTypeController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/emailtype/add/] onto handler 'emailTypeController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/phonetype] onto handler 'phoneTypeController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/phonetype.*] onto handler 'phoneTypeController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/phonetype/] onto handler 'phoneTypeController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/phonetype/.*] onto handler 'phoneTypeController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/phonetype/delete/{phoneTypeId}] onto handler 'phoneTypeController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/phonetype/delete/{phoneTypeId}.*] onto handler 'phoneTypeController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/phonetype/delete/{phoneTypeId}/] onto handler 'phoneTypeController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/phonetype/add] onto handler 'phoneTypeController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/phonetype/add.*] onto handler 'phoneTypeController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/phonetype/add/] onto handler 'phoneTypeController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/salutation] onto handler 'salutationController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/salutation.*] onto handler 'salutationController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/salutation/] onto handler 'salutationController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/salutation/add] onto handler 'salutationController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/salutation/add.*] onto handler 'salutationController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/salutation/add/] onto handler 'salutationController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/salutation/delete/{salutationId}] onto handler 'salutationController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/salutation/delete/{salutationId}.*] onto handler 'salutationController'
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/salutation/delete/{salutationId}/] onto handler 'salutationController'
```

Comment: What URI are you getting a 404 for? Do your logs say anything?

Comment: http://localhost:48080/ContactManagement/contact - I'll get the logs

Comment: I checked the logs...nothing is output when I try to hit the site

Comment: What about startup logs?

Comment: See my updated post above